# Magic square matrices

Tags: combinations, magic-square

A magic square is a square which allow non-negative integers entries in which all row sums and columns sums are equal. 
Let $H_3(r)$ denotes number of magic squares of size $3*3$ in which each row and column have sum equals $r$. Prove that $$H_3(r) =\binom{r+4}{4}+\binom{r+3}{4}+\binom{r+2}{4}$$ where $H_3(r)$ is the number of $3*3$ magic squares of line sum $r$.

I try to find out the relations between all the
$$ \left[
\begin{array}\\
  a&b&c\\
  d&e&f\\
  g&h&i\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
variables. I thought if I manage to built a relation between all the variables so that the values of all variables depend upon any one or two independent variables. But I fail to built such relations among variables.

I asked this question to all my faculty teachers and school teacher, but no answer come up.

If the question is worth, please solve it.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes sir I tried it, but the equations formed are dependent on one another.

Comment: Up to what I see, there are $5$ conditions. [1-4] $\max(a+b, d+e, a+d, b+e ) \le r$ for $c,f,g,h \ge 0$ and [5] $a+b+d+e \ge r$ for $i \ge 0$.

Comment: Usually, the diagonals are also of the same sum in magic squares - I suppose here that's not the case?